# Testing my TLS1.1 connection code

Tags: ssl, windows

I have a desktop client application (Windows) developed using C++. It connects to the web services hosted on the IIS on the server. Currently I am in the process of porting this application to use TLS1.1/1.2 from the existing SSLv3.0/TLS1.0. However, I would like to test my client code separately by connecting to some server which already supports TLS1.1. Is there any tool available that I can use to test the same?

Comment: You should be able to use the [OpenSSL command line](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities#s_server) for this.

Comment: You mean any TLS 1.1 webserver? Maybe even the "openssl s_server" command?